# What are these function and parameter annotations?

Tags: c, gcc, annotations

The source code for busybox's [syslogd implementation](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/sysklogd/syslogd.c#n1100) contains some annotations I'm unfamiliar with. The language is C, not C++.

```
int syslogd_main(int argc, char **argv) MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE;
int syslogd_main(int argc UNUSED_PARAM, char **argv)
```

Specifically, `MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE` and `UNUSED_PARAM`.

1. What exactly are these annotations doing? Where can I read more about them and other annotations?
2. Are these part of the C standard, or are they compiler extensions? If they are compiler extensions, how widely supported are they?
3. I assume the first one is why this file doesn't have a `main()` function. If these are compiler extensions rather than part of the standard, does this mean this file can't be meaningfully compiled as-is by a compiler that adheres only to the C standard?
4. Why did they declare a prototype of the `syslogd_main` function immediately before the full definition? Can the `MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE` annotation only be applied to function prototypes?

Comment: Those almost certainly are macros, and not compiler extensions or part of the C standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### 1. What exactly are these annotations doing?

See [include/platform.h](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/include/platform.h) and [include/libbb.h](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/include/libbb.h)

`UNUSED_PARAM` expands to `__attribute__ ((__unused__))`. It specifies the variable (`argc` in your example) as "possibly unused" and disables the "unused variable" warning.

From the GCC manual [Specifying Attributes of Variables]:

> `unused`
>       This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this variable.

`MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE` expands to `EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE` and then to `__attribute__(( visibility("default") ))`. It controls the visibility of the function.

From the GCC manual [Declaring Attributes of Functions]:

> ... On ELF, default visibility means that the declaration is visible to other modules and, in shared libraries, means that the declared entity may be overridden.

From [include/libbb.h](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/include/libbb.h):

```
/* We need to export XXX_main from libbusybox
 * only if we build "individual" binaries
 */
#if ENABLE_FEATURE_INDIVIDUAL
#define MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE
#else
#define MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE
#endif
```

> #### 2. Are these part of the C standard, or ...?

No, those are macros defined in the BusyBox project.

> #### 3. I assume the first one is why this file doesn't have a main() function. ...

No. BusyBox combines many utilities into a single executable. That explains the "lack of a `main()` function" in `syslogd.c`.

> #### 4. Why did they declare a prototype of the syslogd_main function immediately before the full definition? ...

From the GCC manual [Declaring Attributes of Functions]:

> The keyword `__attribute__` allows you to specify special attributes when making a declaration.

Comment: aha, that format is much more familiar to me. so does this have anything to do with the lack of a `main` function? or the prototype immediately before the definition?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow BusyBox's syslogd is not a standalone application, that's why there is no `main()` function.